# How to add console outputs Node.js app in the log access NGINX file?

Tags: node.js, nginx, systemd

I have an Node.js app setting up with systemd. The app running behind NGINX.
I would like to add console output of my Node.js application in the log access NGINX file ?
How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More simple way is hook `console.log` and call `console.log` as usually.

```
var util = require('util');
var JFile = require("jfile");
var nxFile = new JFile('/var/log/nginx/access.log');
...
process.stdout.write = (function(write) {   
    return function(text, encoding, fd) {
        write.apply(process.stdout, arguments); // write to console
        nxFile.text += util.format.apply(process.stdout, arguments) + '\n'; // write to nginx
     } 
 })(process.stdout.write);
```

Also you can define hook to `console.error` by change `stdout` to `strerr` in code above.

P.S. I don't have nginx to verify code. So code can contains errors :)

Answer (score 1):

## Brief :

Using [JFile](https://github.com/abdennour/jfile) package ,  file logging can be smooth as following :

```
nxFile.text+='\n'+message;
```

## Details :

Add function that logs on both (Terminal+nginx log) , then use it instead of using `console.log` directly :

```
var customLog=function(message){

     console.log(message);
     logNginx(message);
}
```

Then , implement **logNginx** which is called inside **customLog** :

```
    var JFile=require('jfile'); //  "npm install jfile --save" required
    let nxFile=new JFile('/var/log/nginx/access.log'); // check path before if exist in your system . IF no , change it with the available path 
    function logNginx(message){
        nxFile.text+='\n'+message; //append new line in nginx log file
      }
```

---

Don't forget to install JFile `npm install jfile` which makes handling files  done quickly .

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Node as a systemd process, with console.log going to stdout (which I believe is the default), and your goal is just to see the logs (or get them on disk somewhere), there's an easier way than all this Node meddling and hooking.

You should already have access to the console log without doing anything through `journalctl`. For instance, my systemd unit file (at `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service` in this example) looks something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Webapp

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/webapp-dir
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node server.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1984
User=myuser
Group=myuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And running `journalctl -u myapp` shows me the console logs from my app.

If you want, you can also send those logs to the syslog with some additional parameters. I've also added the following to my `[Service]` directory to do so:

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myapp
```

Which results in my logs going to the syslog tagged with `myapp`, where I could filter them into their own log if I wanted to with `rsyslog` filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your nginx script . This should work

```
env NODE_BIN=/usr/bin/node
env SCRIPT_FILE="server.js"
env LOG_FILE=/var/log/logfilename.log
env RUN_AS="root"


$RUN_AS -- $NODE_BIN $SCRIPT_FILE >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
```